Jupyter Hub Docker How do I log into the image?
Trying to install JupyterHub with the following link:
https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/quickstart-docker.html
Can't seem to login tried following the steps of launching a bash within the image and running the following commands but can't login with those credentials.
useradd -r test
passed test


I get to the login page, but unfortunately I can't run the task on a linux environment. It's on a OSX device.

And docker exec -it jupyterhub bash allows you to spawn a shell in your running container just fine?

Yes. I can make users with useradd aswell. As stated in the prompt.
